# How to write the numerator like shown in the image

Tags: math-mode

[image]

"number of" in a separate line and "atoms of element" in the second one and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \[ \text{mass \% elements} = \frac{
    \left(\Centerstack{ number of\\ atoms of element\\ per formula unit} \right)
      \times
      \left(\Centerstack{molar mass\\ of element} \right)}
  {\text{molar mass of compound}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The simplest approach to this is to use a single-column `tabular` to stack up the text with `\left(` and `\right)` surrounding each of these tabulars:

```
\[
  \mbox{mass \% element}=\frac{
    \left(
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        number of\\
        atoms of element\\
        per formula unit
        \end{tabular}
      \right)
      \times
      \left(
        \begin{tabular}{c}
          molar mass\\
          of element
        \end{tabular}
        \right)
  }
  {
    \mbox{molar mass of compound}
    }
    \times
    100\%
\]
```

which gives

[image: image of output from LaTeX of above code]

Comment: Quick question: is there any particular reason for preferring `\mbox` to `\text` here?

Answer (score 5):

For example using `\pmatrix` from plain TeX:

```
$$
  \let\t=\hbox
  \t{mass \% elements} = 
   { \pmatrix{\t{number of}\cr \t{atoms of element}\cr \t{per formula unit}}      
     \times \pmatrix{\t{molar mass}\cr \t{of element}}
     \over 
     \t{molar mass of compound} } \times 100\% 
$$
```

Comment: Thank you a lot

Answer (score 4):

I have chosen an approach using the matrix/array if you prefer.

Here there is my MWE with the packages that generate the same fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet} 
\usepackage{courier}

\begin{document}
\[\textnormal{mass \% element}=\frac{
\begin{pmatrix} \text{number of} \\ \text{atoms of element} \\ \text{per formula unit} \end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix} \text{molar mass} \\ \text{of element} \end{pmatrix}}{\text{molar mass of compound}}\times 100 \%
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]